# Finding search terms in multiple text files via python

Tags: python, parsing, search, text

Have many text files in one folder. How can I able to find search term (for example, some word) in these files to get as a result the name and the pathfile to the documents where this search term is?

I tried suggested modified approach but it shows only first file in a folder and not searching for term:

```
dirname = '/Users/user/Documents/DataText/'
search_terms = ['elevator']

for f in os.listdir(dirname):

    text = open(os.path.join(dirname,f)) 

    text = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

    if any([term in text for term in search_terms]):
        print (f)
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

dirname = '/home/user/mydirectory'
search_terms = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach']

for f in os.listdir(dirname):
    text = '\n'.join( open(os.path.join(dirname,f)).readlines() )
    if any([term in text for term in search_terms]):
        print f
```